# mongodb - group by on ~ 1.3 million records

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

```
{"messageId": "123124", "writtenAt":"2017-04-26T15:16:36.200Z", "updatedAt":"2999-12-31T23:59:59.999Z"}
```

```
{"messageId": "123124", "writtenAt":"2017-04-26T15:21:30.230Z", "updatedAt":"2999-12-31T23:59:59.999Z"}
```

The structure of the collection is above. Aside from the mongo id, it has an id called 'messageId', in a collection we can have multiple entries with same 'messageId' but has different 'writtenAt' field value. Have a compound index: messageId (desc), writtenAt (desc).

Now, wanting to do a group by on messageId so I would only get the the latest one (max writtenAt value).  I have the following query but it's taking very long I haven't even gotten a result yet (more than 10 mins then I stop, collection has over 1.3 million records):

```
db.messages.aggregate(
[{ "$match": { "updatedAt": { "$gte": { "$date": "2021-02-26T06:59:51.738Z" } } } },
{ "$sort": { "messageId": -1, "writtenAt": -1 } },
{ "$group": { "_id": "$messageId", "doc": { "$first": "$$ROOT" } } },
{ "$replaceRoot" : { "newRoot" : "$doc"}}
], {allowDiskUse: true});
```

If I add an explain with executionStats, I can see it's picking up the index:

```
[
        {
            "$cursor" : {
                "query" : {
                    "updatedAt" : {
                        "$gte" : ISODate("2021-02-26T06:59:51.738+0000")
                    }
                }, 
                "sort" : {
                    "messageId" : -1.0, 
                    "writtenAt" : -1.0
                }, 
                "queryPlanner" : {
                    "plannerVersion" : 1.0, 
                    "namespace" : "db.messages", 
                    "indexFilterSet" : false, 
                    "parsedQuery" : {
                        "updatedAt" : {
                            "$gte" : ISODate("2021-02-26T06:59:51.738+0000")
                        }
                    }, 
                    "queryHash" : "3141BBC5", 
                    "planCacheKey" : "6858F892", 
                    "winningPlan" : {
                        "stage" : "FETCH", 
                        "filter" : {
                            "updatedAt" : {
                                "$gte" : ISODate("2021-02-26T06:59:51.738+0000")
                            }
                        }, 
                        "inputStage" : {
                            "stage" : "IXSCAN", 
                            "keyPattern" : {
                                "messageId" : -1.0, 
                                "writtenAt" : -1.0
                            }, 
                            "indexName" : "idx_messageId", 
                            "isMultiKey" : false, 
                            "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                "messageId" : [

                                ], 
                                "writtenAt" : [

                                ]
                            }, 
                            "isUnique" : false, 
                            "isSparse" : false, 
                            "isPartial" : false, 
                            "indexVersion" : 2.0, 
                            "direction" : "forward", 
                            "indexBounds" : {
                                "messageId" : [
                                    "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                                ], 
                                "writtenAt" : [
                                    "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }, 
                    "rejectedPlans" : [

                    ]
                }
            }
        }, 
        {
            "$group" : {
                "_id" : "$messageId", 
                "doc" : {
                    "$first" : "$$ROOT"
                }
            }
        }, 
        {
            "$replaceRoot" : {
                "newRoot" : "$doc"
            }
        }
    ]
```

Any idea how can I can improve?  After retrieving the latest messages by messageId then planning to do some pagination slicing after.

***Removed

Comment: How many records are matching?

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon, you mean how many messageIds has multiple entries with different writtenAts? There are many of them, could be half.

Comment: I guess Manuel asked about the first $match stage. It is the first stage and it's not using an index

Comment: Do you have an index on `updatedAt`?

Comment: I mean: those 2 million records are the collection length or the match results. The index name is `idx_messageId` so, I'm not sure the query is optimized. Moreover, a `projection` could help to reduce the payload size and the memory footprint

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon indexName is irrelevant, it's for people to simplify management. What matters is the keyPattern and it looks fine.

Comment: `updatedAt` is not in the `keyPattern`

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon, it's 1.3million the collection count (I've corrected the 2million)

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit,  I've added and updated the post, getting same results

Comment: @villager Sorry you misread the recommendations. The updateAt at the end of the compound index won't help. In your case an index can be used to sort **or** to filter. The idea was that if number of records after filtering is low enough, it might be more efficient to filter by index and then do in-memory sort. To do so you need another index with "updatedAt " be the only field in the index.

Comment: @AlexBlex, thanks, the result after the filter on updatedAt is ~100k. For in-memory sort, you mean will do it on the app code instead? Is it because only 1 index can be used on aggregation (so either the updatedAt filter index, or the composite sort index)?

Comment: Well, in theory there is "index intersection" functionality but there are so many conditions to make it happen that I've never seen it in real life. It would be safe to count on a single index only. In-memory sort will be done by mongo. All you need to do is to create the second index. Mongo query planner then will decide which one is more efficient on per-query base.

Comment: There are some explanations on how mongo choose which index to use https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/query-plans/ For the sake of testing you can "hint" index name explicitly in the aggregation options

Comment: in your output (which I have a bit trouble to understand) I believe the FETCH (which is abnormaly slow) corresponds to your filter query which would be executed at the very end ??. In any case, you may NOT want a compound index including updatedAt but: a compound index (messageId, writtenAt) AND a single one (updatedAt). The former one for the group stage, and the latest for the filter.